# PHP Smarty Array to string

Tags: php, html, smarty

I know that's common problem with display data in html with smarty. I just started today this morning using smarty, and was checking net /here also/ for solution, but after 3 hours I gave up.

I have error Array to string conversion and have no other ideas what to do. I know that was on forum,but I checked them.

```
<?php
require_once('Smarty.class.php');
//include_once('project_config.php');

$link    = mysqli_connect("localhost", "test", "test", "tcg_test");
$smarty  = new Smarty();


$q = "SELECT person, id FROM person
      WHERE person.type_id = 
      (
          SELECT type_id FROM tcg_test.type 
          WHERE type_key = 'company.owner'
      )";

if($result = mysqli_query($link, $q))
{
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));
}

$rrows     = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
     $rrows[] = $row;
}

$rows_string = implode( "," , $rrows);
$smarty->assign('rrows',$rows_string);

$smarty->display('compare.tpl');
mysqli_free_result($result);

?>
```

HTML

```
        {foreach $rrows as $row}
            {$row}
        {/foreach}
```

And $rrows

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(33) "number 1 ....."
    [1]=>
    string(3) "906"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "number 2...."
    [1]=>
    string(3) "906"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(29) "number 3 ....."
    [1]=>
    string(3) "906"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(25) "number 4....."
    [1]=>
    string(3) "906"
  }
}
```

I came to this:

```
            {section name=record loop=$rrows}
                {foreach from=$rrows[record] item=entry key=name}

                    <option> {$entry} </option>
                 {/foreach}
            {/section}
```

but i dont need number 906

Comment: stop using mysqli_* function, they are deprecated since php5.5 and removed from php7.0 (prevent migration)

Comment: @MTroy `mysql_*` functions have been depreciated, not `mysqli_*`.

Comment: Why do you assign `rrows` a string, but then use it as array in `foreach`?

Comment: So I should just pass array to template and then use foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot implode because $rrows is multi dimensional array

```
$rows_string = implode( "," , $rrows);
```

**Option 1 :**

You may remove this

```
$rows_string = implode( "," , $rrows);
$smarty->assign('rrows',$rows_string);
```

and just pass array to your html

```
$smarty->assign('rrows',$rrows);
```

and you may try using implode in your html
So.. it should be something like this

```
{foreach $rrows as $row}
    {{ ','|implode:$row }}
{/foreach}
```

**Option 2 :**

If you not using $rrows somewhere else you may do implode in your while loop

```
$rrows     = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
     $rrows[] = $row;
}

$rows_string = implode( "," , $rrows);
$smarty->assign('rrows',$rows_string);
```

into something like this

```
$rrows     = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
     $rrows[] = implode( "," , $row);
}

$smarty->assign('rrows', $rrows);
```

Comment: Ok, got it, and if ii want just to have in template "number 1 number 2 number 3", without commas? i came to this what I just edited above, but that gives me number 906 as well.

Comment: Use 'if condition'  in foreach